# How to make a list of environments?

Tags: table-of-contents, programming

I know that `LaTeX`/`TeX` is a complete programming language, but I can not find any topic about making list or vectors, as it is in C# or C++. My goal is to make a list, where I store names of my `\newenvironment` (for example let it be something like section), and refer to it by its number in the list.

The list size must not be constant it should depend on how much time the environment was called. Can this be done? (or should I make a program, which will manipulate the text and then compile it?)

I've wrote an example by writing external file and reading from it, and is it correct?

```
\documentclass{book}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Dotfill}{\leavevmode \cleaders \hb@xt@ .8em{\hss .\hss }\hfill \kern \z@}
\makeatother

\newwrite\contentfile
\immediate\openout\contentfile=\jobname.txt

\newcounter{Section}
\newenvironment{Section}[1]
{   
    \stepcounter{Section}
    \vspace{10pt}
    {\Large{$\S\theSection.$ #1}} \\[5pt]
    \def\theSectionName {#1}

    \immediate\write\contentfile{\string\S \theSection. \theSectionName \string\Dotfill \thepage\string\\}
}


\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\immediate\write\contentfile{\string\begin{center}}
\immediate\write\contentfile{\string\begin{minipage}{10cm}}

\Section{section one}

this is first

\Section{section two}

hjykfkk


\Section{section three}

hjykfkk dfga dfgagr gagergreghah

\newpage

\Section{section four}
hjykfkk dfga dfgagr gagergreghah

\immediate\write\contentfile{\string\end{minipage}}
\immediate\write\contentfile{\string\end{center}}
\immediate\closeout\contentfile
\input{\jobname.txt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That sounds like you simply want to label/ref stuff.

Comment: Well, I tried using them and searched examples, but I was not able to make them work as I needed.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but you rather invent the wheel once more than getting one of the most basic concepts of LaTeX to work?

Comment: LaTeX is about printing documents and not about manipulation objects like other programming languages and so the standard tools are different. Whatever you want to do can quite probably be done (e.g. with expl3) but you should better explain your goal so that you get a suitable advice.

Comment: You can look at it as making table of contents by sections, where you have its name, number and page number.

Comment: The normal way to do that is to write each item out into a file and then read it back in.  That's how `tableofcontents` etc work.  If you want to make your own, then have a look at  (for example) the [`tocloft`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package.

Comment: Could you write an example, because writing I also tried to make external file, but I don't know correct way of using it.

Comment: you give the example of `\section` and to generate a list of sections just use`\tableofcontents` after `\begin{document}` and run latex at least twice. If that is not what you mean, please make a _complete_ small document and say what output you wish to make.

Comment: If you are talking arrays, you can use \csname foo\theindex\endcsname to create \foo1, \foo2, ...  for \newcounter{index}.  If you are talking linked list, you can use \let\Anext=\B (assuming \B is already defined).

Comment: maybe package `etoc` and `minitoc` are looked for for sectionwise `toc`s.

Comment: It has been mentioned before: `expl3` and a `seq` variable should be very useful here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, I think the O.P. tries to reinvent the `\addcontentsline` and `\addtocontents` features, but those can be used without much ado, in my point of view. The `Section` is an example for any other environment.

```
\documentclass{book}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listofenvironments}{%
  \section*{The environments}
  \@starttoc{env}% Starting to show the environment list (file extension `.env`)
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{Section}


\newenvironment{Section}[1]
{%   
    \stepcounter{Section}  % should be \refstepcounter rather?
    \vspace{10pt}
    {\Large{$\S\theSection.$ #1}} \\[5pt] %Is this necessary?
   % Write the number and enviroment name to the `.env` list file 
   \addcontentsline{env}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theSection}~#1}% 
    %  \addtocontents{env}{\protect\contentsline{section}{\theSection~#1}{\thepage}}
}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{env}{\protect\begin{center}}
    \addtocontents{env}{\protect\begin{minipage}{10cm}}
}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \addtocontents{env}{\protect\end{minipage}}
  \addtocontents{env}{\protect\end{center}}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

%\immediate\write\contentfile{\string\begin{center}}
%\immediate\write\contentfile{\string\begin{minipage}{10cm}}

\Section{section one}

this is first

\Section{section two}

hjykfkk


\Section{section three}

hjykfkk dfga dfgagr gagergreghah

\newpage

\Section{section four}
hjykfkk dfga dfgagr gagergreghah


\listofenvironments



\end{document}
```

[image]